# ECR login error: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, docker-registry, aws-serverless, amazon-ecr

[image]

I am trying to build and push the docker image to ECR. I was able to build and push the docker when i freshly created the ECR private repo and all working good, but after 1 day, i am trying to push new image but it give authentication error, so when try to execute login command, TLS handshake error is encountered

Things checked so for:

1. IAM user access to ECRFullAccess, sts:GETAcesssToken
2. AWS cli configure setup with proper access and secrete key
3. Good internet connection 50Mbps
4. Uninstall and installed docker in windows again
5. Deleted ECR repo and created again

Result so for:

1. when i try ecr-login multiple times, it shows login succeeded in 1 or 2 times among 10 attempts
2. when login succeeded, if i try pushing the image, It shows "retrying 3 seconds", "retrying 5 seconds" for some layers and after some time it shows same TLS timeout error